# C++ - substring runtime out of range error (on ROS)

Tags: c++, string, substring, sensors, ros

I'm programming on [ROS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robot_Operating_System) with C++. I have to show the output of a sensor data. The sensor gives me every second the distance between the two modules. And I'm listing this up in the terminal while it's running. So after a while like so 10 mins I get a runtime error. It says:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range' what(): 
basic_string::substr: __pos (which is 979) > this->size() (which is 978) [1]     
10638 abort (core dumped) rosrun ... ...
```

And the code for this is:

```
std::string str1 = ser.read(ser.available());
std::size_t pos = str1.find(str2);

if(pos < str1.npos) {

    str1 = str1.substr(pos + 7);
    pos = str1.find(" m");
    if(pos < str1.find(" m") {

        str1 = str1.substr(0,pos);
        distance = atof(str1.c_str());

        ROS_INFO_STREAM....
        if(distance < stopped_distance && !stopped) {

            msg.//(create a msg to stop)
            //publish the msg

        }
        else if(...) {

            //create a msg to start and publish it
        }
        stopped = false

    }

//...
```

Everything is working fine but I always get this runtime error. Sometimes immediately sometimes it takes a while.
What could be the reason?

And I also have to say that the `string` I'm manipulating is a long one. I have to find the line where **"Range: 0.30 m"** is and take the number.

Comment: Are you sure `str1.substr(pos + 7)` will be a valid position in the string?

Comment: yes, like I said its not a compile error or something. I get like 400 or 500 outputs and no errors. but then its crashing and giving me this error.

Comment: im sorry i wrote the second if statement wrong. its if(pos < str1.npos) and not if(pos < str1.find(" m")

Comment: You wouldn't get a compiler error.  You would get an exception like you are getting.  Before `str1 = str1.substr(pos + 7);` add `if (pos + 7 > str1.size()) std::cout << "pos + 7 is too big";`

Comment: ok I will try it tomorrow. It could be the solution. But why am i getting an output if its to big?